# Class not showing up on Select element when HTML is rendered

Tags: ruby-on-rails

When rails renders this tag, it is not including the class

```
<%= f.collection_select(:native_language, Language.order('language ASC').all, :language, :language, class: "input_standard", :default => [Language.find_by(:language => "English")] ) %>
```

This is what is rendered:

```
<select name="user[native_language]" id="user_native_language">
    <option value="English">English</option>
    <option value="French">French</option>
    <option value="Spanish">Spanish</option>
</select>
```

Why isn't the class showing up? I've tried moving around class: "input_standard" with no luck.

Comment: @tstrass you're right, the answer is in that link, then my answer can be ignored and this post could be marked as duplicate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Rails documentation for `collection_select` is this one: `collection_select(method, collection, value_method, text_method, options = {}, html_options = {})`. If you check it receives two hashes, the first one is `options` and the second one is the `html_options`. The second one is the one where you specify the `class` the html element will have. Something like:

```
<%= f.collection_select(:native_language, Language.order('language ASC').all, :language, :language, {}, {class: "input_standard", :default => [Language.find_by(:language => "English")]} ) %>
```

By te way, what do you want to accomplish with the `default` option ?, should that be the `prompt` option ?.

If you what you want is the `prompt` option instead of the `default`, then you need to add the `prompt` option to the first hash.